# Quaternion.LookRotation on z-up gameEngine

Tags: rotation, quaternion

I'm trying to implement a look rotation method, similar to Unitys one, but with the difference that in Unity, Z is forward, and in my engine, Z is up. I have an implementation where Z is forward, and I'm not able to convert it.

My "engine" is the GTA V .net Script Hook; I'm making a mod. The function is not working as expected. It gives wrong rotations, and I think it's because of the different coordinate systems, as I said above.

This is the function, currently:

```
private static Quaternion LookRotation(Vector3 forward, Vector3 up)
{    
    forward = Vector3.Normalize(forward);
    Vector3 right = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(up, forward));
    up = Vector3.Cross(forward, right);
    var m00 = right.x;
    var m01 = right.y;
    var m02 = right.z;
    var m10 = up.x;
    var m11 = up.y;
    var m12 = up.z;
    var m20 = forward.x;
    var m21 = forward.y;
    var m22 = forward.z;
    float num8 = (m00 + m11) + m22;
    var quaternion = new Quaternion();

    if (num8 > 0f)
    {
        var num = (float)Math.Sqrt(num8 + 1f);
        quaternion.w = num * 0.5f;
        num = 0.5f / num;
        quaternion.x = (m12 - m21) * num;
        quaternion.y = (m20 - m02) * num;
        quaternion.z = (m01 - m10) * num;
        return quaternion;
    }

    if ((m00 >= m11) && (m00 >= m22))
    {
        var num7 = (float)Math.Sqrt(((1f + m00) - m11) - m22);
        var num4 = 0.5f / num7;
        quaternion.x = 0.5f * num7;
        quaternion.y = (m01 + m10) * num4;
        quaternion.z = (m02 + m20) * num4;
        quaternion.w = (m12 - m21) * num4;
        return quaternion;
    }

    if (m11 > m22)
    {
        var num6 = (float)Math.Sqrt(((1f + m11) - m00) - m22);
        var num3 = 0.5f / num6;
        quaternion.x = (m10 + m01) * num3;
        quaternion.y = 0.5f * num6;
        quaternion.z = (m21 + m12) * num3;
        quaternion.w = (m20 - m02) * num3;
        return quaternion;
    }

    var num5 = (float)Math.Sqrt(((1f + m22) - m00) - m11);
    var num2 = 0.5f / num5;
    quaternion.x = (m20 + m02) * num2;
    quaternion.y = (m21 + m12) * num2;
    quaternion.z = 0.5f * num5;
    quaternion.w = (m01 - m10) * num2;

    return quaternion;
}
```

---

As a workaround, I'm doing this:

```
velocityQuaternion = MathR.LookAt(Vector3.Zero, entity.velocity);
```

but it gives the wrong rotations when the entity rotates at extreme angles (when it rolls over, for example). `LookAt` is much like `Transform.LookAt`, in Unity.

---

I'm trying to use `LookRotation` like this:

```
 velocityQuaternion = MathR.LookRotation(veh.Velocity, Vector3.WorldUp); 
 // Vector3.WorldUp is (0f,0f,1f)

 targetCamera.Position = veh.Position + (velocityQuaternion * Vector3.RelativeBack * distance); // Vector3.RelativeBack is (0, -1, 0)
```

The camera shuold be placed rear the vehicle when it goes forward, but instead, it's placed at the right, so you see the bottom side of the vehicle instead of rear (the camera places below the floor itself). If I use the vehicle quarternion instead of velocityQuaternion it works fine

I think this can be useful to determine what the diffrerences between coordinate systems are:

These ones are of the engine I currently use:

```
    // GTAV script hook vector3 shortcuts
    Back vector. (0,-1,0)
    Bottom vector. (0,0,-1)
    Front vector. (0,1,0)
    Left vector.(-1,0,0)
    Right vector. (1,0,0)
    Top vector. (0,0,1)
```

And these ones are of unity (which is left handed) (LookRotation was originally written for this coordinate system)

```
   // Unity vector3 shortcuts
   back => (0, 0, -1).
   down => (0, -1, 0).
   forward => (0, 0, 1).
   left => (-1, 0, 0).
   right => (1, 0, 0).
   up => (0, 1, 0).
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you make a clear request of what assistance you need with this beyond "any ideas?"? It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: The function is not working as expected. It gives wrong rotations, and I think it's because of different coordinate systems, as I said above. In Unity (this function was written originally for Untiy) Z is forward, and in GTA V script hook, Z is up. I basically want the function to work as it should.

Comment: I edited the original question to make more clear what the issue is.

Comment: There's literally a parameter called `up` in your code, set it to `(0, 0, 1)`, it's there for this purpose

Comment: It sems your intending to ask "how do I do this" in a general sense. As such, this question is too broad for our scope.

Comment: I don't think the question is too broad - it's right in the wheelhouse of our other vector math questions - but it is a little under-defined at the moment. Can you tell us more about the coordinate systems we're converting? Knowing which way Z points is only a third of the problem - the orientation of the other two axes tells us whether we're in a left-handed or right-handed system. Including examples of expected vs observed results can also be a big help with debugging "wrong" results - there's lots of ways to be wrong, so the specific *way* it's wrong can tell us a lot about the root issue.

Comment: I've added more info about expected results vs current, and also more about the differences between both coordinate systems.